# generate random opacity number using math random

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, random, opacity

I am trying to generate a random number for the css opacity.

This is what I tried so far.

CSS

```
.test{
    position : absolute;
    width : 15px;
    height : 15px;
    border-radius:15px;
    background-color : black; 
}​
```

Script

```
$(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
        $("<div>", {
            class: "test",
            css: {
                opacity: randomOpacity
            }
        }).appendTo("body");
    }

    function randomOpacity() {
        var opac = 0;
        opac = Math.random() < 1;
        console.log(opac);
    }

    randomize();
});​
```

#### [The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/techydude/pzrsN/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple errors with your fiddle:

- You are spawning 300 divs that are all absolutely positioned. They stack on top of each other and so would appear black regardless.
- You aren't actually calling the function (missing parentheses)
- Math.random() < 1 is going to return True instead of a number.
- You aren't returning opac from your function.
- You were calling randomize(), which isn't defined.

Corrected version: http://jsfiddle.net/RucKd/1/

Comment: I was going to try to make a review of that code too, but good job man. I wouldn't have managed to write all that in less than 20 minutes more. +1

Comment: Also, `randomize()` is not defined in the fiddle so you may remove it from there and add to the error list. `=]`

Comment: `var opac = 0; opac =  Math.random(); return opac;` is plainly redundant as well, `return Math.random();` has the same effect, which makes the use of a function call just unnecessary. But never mind that.

Comment: I stripped down my original code, so some of it is useless in the jsfiddle I wrote. Thank you very much for your help Christophe! 

Is there a way to limit the random number so its random between 0 and .25 max?

Answer (score 2):

[`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) already generates a random number between `0` and `1`, so:

```
$(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        $("<div>", {
            class: "test"
        }).css('opacity', Math.random()).appendTo("body");
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/pzrsN/6/)

**edit:** Re-inserted your loop in my answer and removed absolute pos from the fiddle. Read @ChristopheBiocca (+1)'s answer for a more complete code review.

Answer (score 1):

***JS***

```
 $(function() {

        for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++){
          $("<div>", {
            class : "test",
            css : {
              opacity : randomOpacity
            }
          }).appendTo("body"); 
        }


        function randomOpacity(){
          var opac = 0;
             opac =  (Math.random());
            return opac;
        }

      });
```

***CSS***
remove `position : absolute;`, with this css all your divs at the same place

.test{
        width : 15px;
        height : 15px;
        border-radius:15px;
        background-color : black; 
      }​

Answer (score 0):

The css functions alters a css attribute, `Math.random()` returns 0-1 so you can just drop it in. The following code alters the opac div's opacity.

```
 <div id="opac">
 lalalalala
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#opac").css('opacity', Math.random());
});
</script>
```

`$(document).ready` calls everything inside it once the page is loaded, good idea to use for things like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#foobar').css({ opacity: Math.random() });​
```

Answer (score 0):

`Math.random()` always returns a value between 0 and 1 and you can put it directly in the function that creates `divs`. Also, the `position: absolute` in your CSS places every `div` in the same place, so you are not able to see the result correctly. Try this:

CSS

```
.test{
    width : 15px;
    height : 15px;
    border-radius:15px;
    background-color : black; 
}​
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
        $("<div>", {
            class: "test",
            css: {
                opacity: Math.random()
            }
        }).appendTo("body");
    }
});​
```

Anyway, the `randomize()` function is not defined.